# Angular - append params to URL

Tags: angular, angular-http

I would like to append parameters to url:

```
 let params = [];
 params["p1"] = "value1";
 params["p2"] = "value2";

this.location.go(this.router.createUrlTree([this.data]).toString());
```

When I have this url `localhost/project/page` its work correct. But when I have url `localhost/project/page/id` after append url is `localhost/project/page/p1=..`

I need to keep the parameter in url and add the new one. thanks for advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the button, call a method like the one below?
Here `this.router` is `Router` instance, inject it in your component.

```
onClick(params) {
    this.router.navigate(['project', 'page', {id : id}], {queryParams: {p1: params['p1'], p2: params['p2']}});
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I think, this updates my page. I dont want it. does the id stay in the url?

Comment: If there is an `id` add the variable under the `navigate` method.

Comment: Ok but sometimes I dont have id in url.

Answer (score 0):

You can send params in the routing like below -

```
[routerLink]="['project/page','params']"
```

If you wish to send it as `query params` send it like this -

```
<a [routerLink]="['project/page']" [queryParams]="{ page: 99 }">Your caption</a>
```

Comment: I can not use this. I would like to add param to url after click for button and I can not redirect page.