# How should I share my entity id between routes in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a crud in angular splited in 2 components: List and Form. One to show the available entries and another to edit it. A service is using to share the registry's id from the list to form component, that way I can load the whole entity from the server when form inits. The problem is when user use the browser tab to navigate directly to forms route. The app is reloaded, the service lost the state and the console is exploded with undefined reference exceptions.

There is a clean way to avoid this situation? I was thinking about share the id at route param, but some entities uses composite key and I don't know if use lot of params like that `'form\:id1\:id2\:id3\:id4'` is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple id as

```
?id=123+134+1234+187
```

or

```
?id1=123&id2=1245&id3=7889
```

Also you can check below link to check ho to add parama to url

[Angular - append params to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717113/angular-append-params-to-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a param and rest as query params

```
form\:id1?id2=<id2>&id3=<id3>
```

Otherwise form will look like as list page and these query params as search options.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing called optional params in angular routing.

Check the link and it should be a useful solution. You do not need to define in routing configurations as they are optional params. A thorough example has been given in link: 
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/parameterised-routes/#_optional_parameters